# Alguem sabe me explicar o porque não está rodando?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    float n1,n2;
    do {
        printf("Informe dois numeos:");
        scanf("%f %f", &n1, &n2);
        if (n1>n2){
          printf("DECRESCENTE"); }
        else {
          printf("CRESCENTE"); }
}
    while (n1!=n2);
     system("pause");

}
```

Alguém sabe me dizer porque não ta rodando?
Da esses erros

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe   cannot open output
>   file C:\Users\Andressa Lilja\Desktop\IF\PROGRAMAÇÃO\5.4.exe:
>   Permission denied
>   C:\Users\Andressa Lilja\Desktop\IF\PROGRAMAÇÃO\collect2.exe   [Error] ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Como você está compilando o programa?

Comment: Apesar de não parecer muito bem escrito, o código esta compilando, [teste aqui](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php)

Comment: Qual compilador estás a usar ?

Answer (score 0):

Para usar o system("pause") você precisa da biblioteca stdlib.h
Eu não sei qual o erro que você encontrou ai, mas pelo que vi é isso.

AH, vi o erro, normalmente você executou o código, e a janela ainda está aberta, e você teclou pra compilar de novo. Você tem que finalizar o programa, pra executar ele de novo, se não da esse erro ai.